# Should a WordPress plugin polyfill the global JS environment?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a JS-heavy WordPress plugin with babel/WebPack to transpile ES6 -> ES5 code. I'm also relying on some of the new features, like `Promise` and `Object.assign`, and I'm wondering a few things:

1. Does WordPress ship any polyfills of its own for the global environment?
2. What are best practices around handling/shipping polyfills in WordPress plugins?

Comment: Probably not to use JS at all ;)

Comment: on a more serious note, if you are talking about frontend, do whatever you want. backend, just avoid any complex JS

Comment: Lol but not really. https://wptavern.com/state-of-the-word-2015-javascript-and-api-driven-interfaces-are-the-future-of-wordpress

Comment: yes we hear the same BS for the last 7 years, and it always ends up the same way as "the year of the linux on desktop" ends. JS is a moving target which is hard to debug. The less you use it, the longer you will avoid white hair

Comment: WordPress still supports PHP 5.2 in 2017, REST API opens the door for everything, that's true - but IMHO manned mission to Mars will happen before JS becomes the 'future' of WP.

Comment: JS _already_ is the future of WordPress. The codebase is increasingly reliant on JS for complex functionality, and they're going to push more of the wp-admin functionality into the REST API, but WP is a large project and things take time to change. I want to see more JS in WP, and I'm curious what other people think about how we should do that in our own work.

Comment: You made me laugh. The JS code in wordpress is treated generally as "here be dragons" on historical maps. Poorly documented, hard to read, hard to extend. If that is the future of wordpress then wordpress is even in a worse shape than people think it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does WordPress ship any polyfills of its own for the global environment?

No, as far as I remember WP core doesn't ship with any polyfills.

> What are best practices around handling/shipping polyfills in WordPress plugins?

The typical practice for JS in public WP extensions is to either:

1. stick with core–provided scripts/environment;
2. isolate your code and dependencies from impacting global state, by use of noConflict modes or otherwise.

If you *have* to deal with global state in public extension — be prepared for it to explode in most peculiar ways out there in the wild.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** since [around September 2018](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/9794), WordPress core *does* ship with a polyfill, `wp-polyfill`, which appears to be [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill/)'s browser library, and I expect is down to all the React in the Gutenberg editor. You can find it here:

```
wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/wp-polyfill.js
```

You can add `wp-polyfill` as a dependency when enqueueing your own scripts, for example if you need jQuery and polyfills:

```php
wp_enqueue_script(
    'main_custom_script', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/scripts.min.js', 
    array('jquery', 'wp-polyfill'), 
    '1.0', 
    true
);
```

Unfortunately, adding multiple copies of this polyfill [ends in tears](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4019), so it still is sensible not to be including other copies of this polyfill with any plugins you develop, and to stick with this core script.

Another polyfilling alternative to consider is https://polyfill.io/v3/, where you can be selective about the polyfills you want.